# Generalize similar function with different parameters

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, refactoring

Imagine two type of content in an app: "Songs" and "Films".

I have two helper methods that are really similar:

```
/**
 * @protected <-- No need to validate arguments, as the method is "protected".
 * ...
 */
function fillRemainingSongsList(currentSongs, currentUserId) {
  const remainingSongs = MAX_LIST_SIZE - currentSongs.length; 
  const shouldFetchTrending = Math.random() < FETCH_TRENDING_PROBABILITY;
  const promises = [
    api.songs.getRandomSongs(), 
    shouldFetchTrending ? api.songs.getTrendingSongs() : undefined
  ];

  const [
    randomSongs = [],
    trendingSongs = [],
  ] = await Promise.all(promises);

  return [...currentSongs, ...randomSongs, ...trendingSongs];
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @protected
 * ...
 */
async function fillRemainingFilmsList(currentFilms, category) {
  const remainingFilms = MAX_LIST_SIZE - currentFilms.length; 
  const shouldFetchTrending = Math.random() < FETCH_TRENDING_PROBABILITY;
  const promises = [
    api.films.getRandomFilms(category), 
    shouldFetchTrending ? api.films.getTrendingFilms(category) : undefined
  ];

  const [
    randomFilms = [],
    trendingFilms = [],
  ] = await Promise.all(promises);

  return [...currentFilms, ...randomFilms, ...trendingFilms];
}
```

As you can see, there is code repetition in both functions. How can I do to generalize them more? Any design pattern?

The problem I am handling is that both methods calls to different api methods, and have different parameters... but, in the other hand, I am trying to not repeat my self in the logic.

Comment: Instead of `api.songs.getRandomSongs()` and `api.films.getRandomFilms()`, ideally, to make it easier to generalize, it should be `api.xxx.getRandom()`. That way, you could just do `api[xxx].getRandom()`. Same for `getTrending`.

Comment: when `Promse.all(promises)` is resolved, which type of response do you get for films & songs? as you are using `Destructuring` do you get  `randomSongs `, `trendingSongs `, `randomFilms `, `trendingFilms ` keys from BE ? I just want to know the response or response type.

Comment: the response type is an array of objects, for each method.

Comment: This could be further generalized by passing in an object for the `randomXxx` function. Tangential, but it’s not clear what `remainingXxx` is for since it’s not used, but naming-wise it doesn’t match the other names, which is confusing—I suspect it’s closer to `fillCount` or something—it’s a count, not a list of films or songs.

Comment: @NikhilShah OP intends it to be an array as indicated by the default values; there’s no object destructuring and no object keys are referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the random and trending functions into the common refactored function. To cater to the differences in how the different trending functions behave (one requires no parameters and one requires a category) you can wrap them in functions:

```
async function fillRemaining(currentItems, getRandomFn, getTrendingFn) {
  const remainingItems = MAX_LIST_SIZE - currentItems.length; // this is never used?
  const shouldFetchTrending = Math.random() < FETCH_TRENDING_PROBABILITY;
  const promises = [
    getRandomFn(), 
    shouldFetchTrending ? getTrendingFn() : undefined
  ];

  const [
    randomItems = [],
    trendingItems = [],
  ] = await Promise.all(promises);

  return [...currentItems, ...randomItems, ...trendingItems];
}
```

Now both functions can call the refactored function:

```
function fillRemainingSongsList(currentSongs, currentUserId) {

  function getRandom () {
    return api.songs.getRandomSongs();
  }

  function getTrending () {
    return api.songs.getTrendingSongs();
  }

  return fillRemaining(currentSongs, getRandom, getTrending);
}
```

The above function is written with named functions for clarity. Alternatively you can use anonymous functions:

```
async function fillRemainingFilmsList(currentFilms, category) {

  return fillRemaining(
    currentFilms,
    () => api.films.getRandomFilms(category),
    () => api.films.getTrendingFilms(category)
  );
}
```

Both styles do exactly the same thing.